# Google sheet sidebar onclose custom script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

Can I assign custom script to x-close button on sidebar? 
I would like assign to this x-button the same script that is assigned to Close button [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg0FK.png) x-button is yellow marked

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

A sidebar is created inside an iframe and the "x-close" is *outside* the iframe. Though  you *can* control (so, to speak) the contents of your own html environment, you can't modify elements outside the iframe. I won't repeat the technical details; they are well explained in this topic: [How to add CSS property to elements outside iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056570/).